# Cairngorm Fault Handler

Tags: apache-flex, cairngorm

According to Cairngorm architecture, we always have a fault handler in every command class for each service.

How we can create a single Class for handling Fault handler event for all the services.

Comment: But the thing is that i want to handle result in its relative command class but wanna handle fault handler in a global class. I didn't get exactly how we cana achieve it. Can anybody give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

Create a base class that you extend all other classes from, put the fault handler there.  Such as:
FaultHandlerCairngormCommand extends SequenceCommand implements IResponder

[BaseCommand.as]

```
public class BaseCommand extends SequenceCommand implements IResponder
{
    public function execute( event:CairngormEvent ):void 
    {
        super.execute(event);
    }

    public function fault( info:Object ):void 
    {
        throw new Error("Generic request failure"); //or handle as you please
    }
    public function result(data:Object):void
    {
        throw new Error("The result method implementation defined in IResponder for all extensions of BaseCommand must be overrriden in any sub-class");
    }
}
```

[MyCommand.as]

```
// -- no need to implement onFault in sub-class
public class MyCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    public function execute( event:Event ):void 
    {
        remoteObjectDelegate.doYourServerOperation(this);
    }
    override public function result(data:Object):void
    {
        trace("happily handling the data"); //without this override an error will be thrown so the developer will know to correct
    }
}
```

Comment: But the thing is that i want to handle result in its relative command class but wanna handle fault handler in a global class.

Answer (score 1):

By "always having a fault handler", do you mean by contract, as in in implementing an interface?

You can write a base command class that all of your other command classes extend. The base can implement the on fault handler and all other sub-classes can optionally override it.

```
public class BaseCommand implements ICommand
{
    public function execute( event:Event ):void 
    {

    }

    public function onFault( event:Event ):void 
    {

    }
}

// -- no need to implement onFault in sub-class
public class MyCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    public function execute( event:Event ):void 
    {

    }
}
```